# How to use Intellij shortcuts in eclipse/ Spring Tool Suite?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, spring-tool-suite

I have found many articles on doing it the other way round. i.e using eclipse shortcuts in intellij. But I am currently using Spring Tool Suite and I want to **use intellij shortcuts**. Any idea on how one can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse gives you the ability to customize the key sequences bound to functions.  You can get to this at "Preferences->Keys".

However, this will most likely be a somewhat informative waste of time.  The thing is, Eclipse and IntelliJ are completely different applications.  They both are aimed at editing source files and assisting software development, but all of their internal mechanisms and functions are different.

If you're going to be using Eclipse/STS, I suggest you simply learn how to use it effectively.  It allows for a lot of customization, but in different ways than IntelliJ is customized.

Personally, I have almost no experience with IntelliJ, except for briefly using Android Studio several years ago.  I've been using Eclipse since soon after the first release.